# movie ratings user_id index

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to build a movie recommendation system using ratings.csv. I built a ratings matrix using a pivot() by user_id and movie_id.

```
mydf = mydf.pivot(index='user_Id', columns='movie_Id', values='rating').fillna(0).astype(int)

mymatrix = mydf.as_matrix()
```

Comment: What are you getting as output right now? @carlah

Comment: Please see the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
dict(zip(list(mydf.index), list(range(len(mydf.index)))))

{22: 0, 23: 1, 25: 2, 31: 3, 142: 4}
```

Here is the full code

```
user_Id;movie_Id;rating
22;453;0
23;545;1
25;642;2
31;237;3
142;348;4

import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
mydf = mydf.pivot(index='user_Id', columns='movie_Id', values='rating').fillna(0).astype(int)


dict(zip(list(mydf.index), list(range(len(mydf.index)))))

{22: 0, 23: 1, 25: 2, 31: 3, 142: 4}
```